# Select all fields(datetime) where hour is greather than a certain hour and the day is just the current day

Tags: mysql, sql, select

probably the title is a little tricky.
I have this table:

```
| id_ordineX | data_start          |
+------------+---------------------+
| ordine1    | 2018-08-06 08:00:00 |
| ordine1    | 2018-08-06 10:45:00 |
| ordine2    | 2018-08-06 16:20:00 |
| ordine2    | 2018-08-07 09:20:00 |
```

I want to select all fields where `data_start > 2018-08-06 09:00:00`, in this way I get as a result all the last 3 field but I want to select just the result from the day `2018-08-06`, so basically I want to get just the second and the third field.
How can I select just the date in a datetime format?

Comment: Between '2018-08-06 00:09:00' and '2018-08-06 23:59:59' .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple datetime functions can be used:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `data_start` > '2018-08-06 09:00:00' AND DATE(`data_start`) = '2018-08-06';
```

Or you could specify a range:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `data_start` BETWEEN '2018-08-06 09:00:00' AND '2018-08-06 23:59:59';
```

Comment: I would go with option 2.

Comment: The queries are not the same: the first excludes `09:00:00`, the second includes `09:00:00`. One of the reasons I prefer > and < to `between`, especially when dates are concerned.

Answer (score 2):

You could use date and hour

```
select * 
from my_table 
where date(date_start) = curdate() 
      and hour(date_start) > 9
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing the query as:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `table` t
WHERE `data_start` > '2018-08-06 09:00:00' AND  
      `data_start` < '2018-08-07';
```

By avoiding functions on `data_start`, the `WHERE` conditions make it more likely than an index -- if available -- will be used for the query.

I also think this does a very good job of describing the logic you want to implement.